pthreads_cross.h error: conflicting declaration of C function from pthread.h
I have a cmake project where I'm using vcpkg as a package manager. One of the dependencies I need is the apriltag dependency which is dependent on the pthread dependency.
the project seems to configure and download the dependencies perfectly fine. Here is a copy of the cmake output for the configuration:
[cmake] -- Running vcpkg install - done
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
[cmake] -- Found Threads: TRUE
[cmake] -- Found Protobuf: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/tools/protobuf/protoc.exe (found version "25.1.0")
[cmake] -- Found TIFF: optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/tiff.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/tiffd.lib (found version "4.6.0")
[cmake] -- Found FFMPEG: optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/avdevice.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/avdevice.lib;optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/avfilter.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/avfilter.lib;optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/avformat.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/avformat.lib;optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/avcodec.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/avcodec.lib;optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/swresample.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/swresample.lib;optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/swscale.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/swscale.lib;optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/avutil.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/avutil.lib
[cmake] -- Found HDF5: hdf5::hdf5-shared (found version "1.14.4")
[cmake] -- Found ZLIB: optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found suitable version "1.3.1", minimum required is "1")
[cmake] -- Found LibArchive: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/archive.lib (found version "3.7.2")
[cmake] -- Found OpenCV: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows (found version "4.8.0")
[cmake] -- Found PThreads4W: optimized;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/lib/pthreadVC3.lib;debug;C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/pthreadVC3d.lib
[cmake] -- PThreads4W_DLL_DIR: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/../bin
[cmake] -- PThreads4W_DEBUG_DLL_DIR: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/../debug/bin
[cmake] -- Found required Ceres dependency: Eigen version 3.4.0 in C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/eigen3
[cmake] -- Found Ceres version: 2.1.0 installed in: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed with components: [EigenSparse, SparseLinearAlgebraLibrary, Multithreading]
[cmake] -- Found nlohmann_json: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/share/nlohmann_json/nlohmann_jsonConfig.cmake (found version "3.11.3")
[cmake] -- Configuring done (61.0s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Public/wpical/build

but when I try to build the project, I get many errors:
FAILED: CMakeFiles/WPIcal.dir/src/cpp/main.cpp.obj 
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\c++.exe -DGFLAGS_IS_A_DLL=1 -DGLOG_NO_ABBREVIATED_SEVERITIES -DGLOG_USE_GFLAGS -DGLOG_USE_GLOG_EXPORT -DH5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB -IC:/Users/Public/wpical/src/include -IC:/Users/Public/wpical/wpigui/src/include -isystem C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include -isystem C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/eigen3 -isystem C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/apriltag /Zc:__cplusplus -MD -MT CMakeFiles/WPIcal.dir/src/cpp/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\WPIcal.dir\src\cpp\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/WPIcal.dir/src/cpp/main.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/Public/wpical/src/cpp/main.cpp
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/thread:45,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/glog/logging.h:51,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/internal/fixed_array.h:42,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/internal/array_selector.h:38,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/internal/autodiff.h:147,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/autodiff_cost_function.h:130,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/ceres.h:37,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/src/include/fieldcalibration.h:9,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/src/cpp/main.cpp:5:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h: In function 'bool std::operator==(thread::id, thread::id)':
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:26: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type' and 'std::thread::native_handle_type')
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                |                |
      |                |                std::thread::native_handle_type
      |                std::thread::native_handle_type
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/memory:65,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/autodiff_cost_function.h:128:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/allocator.h:237:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const allocator<_Tp1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)'
  237 |     operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/allocator.h:237:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::allocator<_Tp1>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:62,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/memory:66:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:812:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>&, const pair<_T1, _T2>&)'
  812 |     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:812:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:63,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/memory:69:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:448:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)'
  448 |     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:448:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:493:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)'
  493 |     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:493:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1678:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr bool std::operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)'
 1678 |     operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1678:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1748:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator> constexpr bool std::operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)'
 1748 |     operator==(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1748:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:36,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/memory:78:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/tuple:1905:5: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> constexpr bool std::operator==(const tuple<_UTypes ...>&, const tuple<_UTypes ...>&)'
 1905 |     operator==(const tuple<_TElements...>& __t,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/tuple:1905:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::tuple<_UTypes ...>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:829:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Dp, class _Up, class _Ep> bool std::operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, 
_Dp>&, const unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&)'
  829 |     operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:829:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:837:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Dp> bool std::operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&, nullptr_t)'    
  837 |     operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x, nullptr_t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:837:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:845:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Dp> bool std::operator==(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)'    
  845 |     operator==(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:845:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/iosfwd:42,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:52,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/memory:80:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/postypes.h:192:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const fpos<_StateT>&, const fpos<_StateT>&)'
  192 |     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/postypes.h:192:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::fpos<_StateT>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:53:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1793:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp1, class _Tp2, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>&, const __shared_ptr<_Tp2, _Lp>&)'
 1793 |     operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __a,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1793:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1799:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>&, nullptr_t)'
 1799 |     operator==(const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __a, nullptr_t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1799:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1819:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> bool std::operator==(nullptr_t, const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>&)'
 1819 |     operator==(nullptr_t, const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __a) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1819:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:555:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Up> bool std::operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>&, const shared_ptr<_Tp>&)'
  555 |     operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a, const shared_ptr<_Up>& __b) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:555:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:561:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>&, nullptr_t)'
  561 |     operator==(const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a, nullptr_t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:561:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:582:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(nullptr_t, const shared_ptr<_Tp>&)'
  582 |     operator==(nullptr_t, const shared_ptr<_Tp>& __a) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:582:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/internal/autodiff.h:143:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/array:297:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, long long unsigned int _Nm> bool std::operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>&, const array<_Tp, _Nm>&)'
  297 |     operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/array:297:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/vector:66,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/internal/array_selector.h:36:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:2037:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)'
 2037 |     operator==(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:2037:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:47,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string:54,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/ios:44,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/istream:40,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/sstream:40,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/complex:45,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/Eigen/Core:50,
                 from C:/Users/Public/wpical/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/ceres/internal/fixed_array.h:33:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:608:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> constexpr bool std::operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)'
  608 |     operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:608:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   '__ptw32_handle_t' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:615:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> constexpr bool std::operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>, __type_identity_t<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >)'
  615 |     operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:615:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   '__ptw32_handle_t' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:641:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits> constexpr bool std::operator==(__type_identity_t<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> >, basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)'
  641 |     operator==(__type_identity_t<basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>> __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/string_view:641:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:330:33: note:   '__ptw32_handle_t' is not derived from 'std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>'
  330 |     return __x._M_thread == __y._M_thread;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I am currently developing on windows 10:
gcc (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0
cmake version 3.30.0-rc4
vcpkg package management program version 2024-07-10-d2dfc73769081bdd9b782d08d27794780b7a99b9
this is my CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "$ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

project(WPIcal)

set(OSBitness 64)
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
    set(OSBitness 32)
endif()

set(FullOutputDir "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}${OSBitness}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${FullOutputDir}")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${FullOutputDir}")

find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(apriltag CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(ceres CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/cpp/main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/wpigui/src/include
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    opencv_core
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_highgui
    opencv_video
    opencv_videoio
    Ceres::ceres
    Eigen3::Eigen
    nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
    apriltag::apriltag
)

this is my vcpkg.json file:
{
  "dependencies": [
    "apriltag",
    {
      "name": "ceres",
      "features": [
        "eigensparse"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "opencv4",
      "features": [
        "ffmpeg",
        "contrib"
      ]
    },
    "eigen3",
    "nlohmann-json",
    "glfw3",
    "imgui"
  ]
}

and this is my file structure:
wpical
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── error.txt
├── src
│   ├── cpp
│   │   ├── cameracalibration.cpp
│   │   ├── fieldcalibration.cpp
│   │   └── main.cpp
│   └── include
│       ├── cameracalibration.h
│       └── fieldcalibration.h
├── vcpkg.json
└── wpigui
    └── src
        ├── cpp
        │   ├── portable-file-dialogs.cpp
        │   ├── wpigui.cpp
        │   ├── wpigui_directx11.cpp
        │   ├── wpigui_metal.mm
        │   ├── wpigui_opengl2.cpp
        │   ├── wpigui_opengl3.cpp
        │   └── wpigui_openurl.cpp
        └── include
            ├── portable-file-dialogs.h
            ├── wpigui.h
            ├── wpigui_internal.h
            └── wpigui_openurl.h

So far, I've updated msys2, vcpkg, and cmake, but the error still persists.
The really weird thing is that this project builds perfectly fine in a gradle environment, with no build errors about conflicting declarations.
I appreciate any insight on the issue, thanks so much!
edit: add github reference:
https://github.com/ElliotScher/wpical

Please do not post links to error messages.  Edit your question and add them directly.

sorry, it has been fixed.

You configure your project for MinGW (-G "MinGW Makefiles"). I don't know why vcpkg decides to build libraries with Visual Studio (x64-windows, Compiler found: <...>/cl.exe), but those are definitely not compatible with MinGW.

@Tsyvarev should I be using a different -G argument?

You could try Visual Studio 2022 generator, yes. But I wonder why vcpkg behaves so...
